Zusammen oder getrennt: "Beim Tür_öffnen"?
hier im südhessischen ländlichen Dorf, wo ich inzwischen -ähm- besonderes Deutsch gewohnt bin, begegnete mir gerade ein Text, von dem ich sofort meinte, er sei falsch, mir aber nach Diskussionen doch nicht mehr so sicher bin:

Beim Schränkchen öffnen sah ich das [Foto]

Meiner Meinung nach müsste man Schränkchenöffnen (wie auch "das Türöffnen") zusammen schreiben, da der Artikel davor sich ja auf den Vorgang als ganzes bezieht. Andernfalls, also um es getrennt zu schreiben, müsste man -so denke ich- "Beim Öffnen des Schränkchens" schreiben. Ich denke bei meiner Annahme an die Substantivierung. Trifft das zu?
Und vorallem: was ist denn nun richtig? "Beim Schränkchenöffnen" oder "Beim Schränkchen öffnen"?

Zitat von https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D82:

Wortgruppen mit einem Infinitiv (Infinitivgruppen) können substantiviert werden. Wenn die zugrunde liegende Wortgruppe aus zwei Wörtern besteht, wird die Substantivierung zusammen- und großgeschrieben ‹§ 43 E, § 57 (2)›.
Zum Beispiel

Kuchen backen → beim Kuchenbacken
Unkraut jäten → das Unkrautjäten
Sprachen lernen → das Sprachenlernen
Schlittschuh laufen → das Schlittschuhlaufen
auswendig lernen → zum Auswendiglernen
sich ausweinen → das Sichausweinen


